# Scipy dendrogram leaf label colours

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Is it possible to assign colours to leaf labels of dendrogram plots from Scipy? I can't figure it out from the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html). Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram

distanceMatrix = pdist(subj1.ix[:,:3])
dendrogram(linkage(distanceMatrix, method='complete'), 
           color_threshold=0.3, 
           leaf_label_func=lambda x: subj1['activity'][x],
           leaf_font_size=12)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`dendrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) uses matplotlib to create the plot, so after you've called `dendrogram`, you can manipulate the plot however you like.  In particular, you can modify the attributes of the x axis labels, including the color.  Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mat = np.array([[1.0,  0.5,  0.0],
                [0.5,  1.0, -0.5],
                [1.0, -0.5,  0.5],
                [0.0,  0.5, -0.5]])

dist_mat = mat
linkage_matrix = linkage(dist_mat, "single")

plt.clf()

ddata = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
                   color_threshold=1,
                   labels=["a", "b", "c", "d"])

# Assignment of colors to labels: 'a' is red, 'b' is green, etc.
label_colors = {'a': 'r', 'b': 'g', 'c': 'b', 'd': 'm'}

ax = plt.gca()
xlbls = ax.get_xmajorticklabels()
for lbl in xlbls:
    lbl.set_color(label_colors[lbl.get_text()])

plt.show()
```

Here's the plot produced by the example:

[image: example plot]

Comment: do NOT give distance matrix to linkage() as input yet since it will consider it observation vectors:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2614

Comment: has this been fixed yet? ive been using distance matrices that are square. what else would we give it? a pdist?

Comment: How to do if label contains unichar? I'm getting an error and I suppose it is related to this.

Comment: @Sigur, if you can't find an answer after searching stackoverflow, create a new question.  I don't think the comments are the place to deal with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! After creating the dendrogram, you can grab the current figure and make modifications.

```
dendrogram(
    Z, 
    leaf_rotation = 90.,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size = 10., # font size for the x axis labels)
    labels = y # list of labels to include 
    ) 

ax = plt.gca()
x_lables = ax.get_xmajorticklabels()
for x in x_labels:
        x.set_color(colorDict[x.get_text()])
```

Hope this helps!